# Automatic way to put all classes in separate files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring

I've started to refactor/clean up big project. Some of files contains few small classes or few enums (yeah, it is very messy;/ ).
 Is there some method or tool to automatically divide files with few enums/classes and create separate files for each of them?

As Fredrik Mörk said - Resharper is very good tool and has possibility to do what I need. But of course as almost all good tools it costs (for one it is cheap, for another not:) ).

Maybe there is some free tool for such simple refactoring? (my boss will not pay for Resharper - he told me that I need 'hammer' not a whole workshop:) )

Comment: I don't know of any but you could probably write a small app to do that pretty quick...just an idea.

Comment: @Richard: It's probably not overly hard to write that but if it takes more than a handful of hours a Resharper license is cheaper, and comes with loads of other goodies ;o)

Comment: Or, download the Resharper trial, use that for your quick refactor and you're all good.

Comment: It is so ABSOLUTELY RIDICULOUS that a 1000 bucks "professional" tool can't do that by its own!!

Comment: It's coming now.. in VS2017 lol

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has a refactoring that [moves a type to a separate file](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_File.html). Might be that it can be applied on a higher level (as project); don't have it installed on this machine to verify though.

Edit: noticed in the online help that there is a refactoring called [Move Types Into Matching Files](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Move_Types_into_Matching_Files.html) that does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, it works on whole projects! Right click on project -> Refactor -> Move types into matching files...

Comment: @Daniel: thanks for the verification. Also found something in the online help (guess that is the refactoring you are referring to?).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also see the update to my comment.

Comment: How is it that is sat `F6`, `i`, `Enter`ing over a hundred times before i came across your answer. @FredrikMörk - you're a rockstar!!!

Answer (score 5):

[CodeRush xpress (free)](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) also supports [Moving a type into a matching file](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/types.xml)

[image]

Comment: you might consider marking duplicates, instead of duplication answers.

Comment: @bummi: you are right, but I guess it's more useful to future visitors to have this new option right here.

Comment: its not free! Resharper is better in that case!